# jQuery's jquery.min.map not found with nested resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using nested resources in my Ruby on Rails 4.0 application, using these routes:

```
resources :stories do
    resources :chapters  
end
```

After playing about with the form, and the paths I got it all working, apart from one persistent error I can't find out how to remove:

```
Started GET "/stories/1/chapters/jquery.min.map" for 192.168.202.1 at 2013-08-19 18:40:57 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stories/1/chapters/jquery.min.map"):
```

As I have looked in both the `Application.html.erb` layout, and the relevant inner layouts, I am assuming [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) is trying to load that file, but failing thanks to the nested resources.