# jQuery static .map file request

Tags: jquery

I've included jquery-1.10.2.min.js in a project and now noticing a 2nd request to the server (after the page loads of course) for: jquery-1.10.2.min.map.  It must be a static file reference (similar to an image) but my phantom page handler does not know the extension .map so this is mapped to my homepage.

Mapping this to my homepage is obviously wrong, but I'm not sure what the intent is here.  Should I add .map to my list of static file types and what is this?

Karl..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320451/jquery-min-map-not-found-with-nested-resources

Comment: Its a duplicate.  I appreciate the link, and it looks like the solution exists there as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Comment: See the answer [here][1] (stackoverflow link).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found